# Create module variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, class-variables

Is there any way to create a variable in a module in Ruby that would behave similar to a class variable? What I mean by this is that it would be able to be accessed without initializing an instance of the module, but it can be changed (unlike constants in modules).

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Ruby natively supports class variables in modules, so you can use class variables directly, and not some proxy or pseudo-class-variables:

```
module Site
  @@name = "StackOverflow"

  def self.setName(value)
    @@name = value
  end

  def self.name
    @@name
  end
end

Site.name            # => "StackOverflow"
Site.setName("Test")
Site.name            # => "Test"
```

Comment: +1 Actually, I have been thinking that the term 'class variable' is misleading. Classes are special cases of modules, and class variables are definable on modules. They should be called module variables.

Comment: @sawa: It's somewhat misleading, but it's what Ruby itself uses: `defined?(@@foo) => "class variable"`.

Comment: Or they could be called static fields. Seems that's what they are.

Comment: @coreyward Hey my mistake. Why the need for two '@@' class variables? Isn't it considered a code smell, especially if the class is extended to use class variables? I was testing this and I realized I could get the same result from a single `@` instance variable. Is there a specific reason for using class variables? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @feed_me_code It's just a part of the language. A class variable is on the actual class, not an instance of the class. In most cases these will behave similarly, but not always. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890118/what-does-variable-mean-in-ruby for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: why the different calls at the end: `T.get` and `T::get` ?

Comment: @intrixius This being so long ago I'm not sure what prompted me to use the `::` notation, perhaps just an effort to show that there are multiple ways of accessing the methods. These two are essentially identical in behavior, but the dot notation is preferred.

Comment: The only thing I probably remove is the Setter, that's breaking the Open/Close Principle from SOLID. If you need to mutate the value highly suggest to use a Instance Variable.

Answer (score 32):

If you do not need to call it from within an instance, you can simply use an instance variable within the module body.

```
module SomeModule
  module_function
  def param; @param end
  def param= v; @param = v end
end

SomeModule.param
# => nil
SomeModule.param = 1
SomeModule.param
# => 1
```

The instance variable `@param` will then belong to the module `SomeModule`, which is an instance of the `Module` class.

Answer (score 26):

you can set a class instance variable in the module.

```
module MyModule
   class << self; attr_accessor :var; end
end

MyModule.var = 'this is saved at @var'

MyModule.var    
=> "this is saved at @var"
```

Comment: +1, but I'll just emphasize that class instance variables are different to class variables.

Comment: Btw also the encapsulation of the ATTR should not be 'read and write' should be just 'read': 

class << self; attr_reader :var; end

And even that is not the proper solution for this case

Comment: @Julian not sure what you mean, this is just an example and you can use `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` depending on your use case

Answer (score 9):

You can also initialize value within module definition:

```
module MyModule
  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_variable
  end
  self.my_variable = 2 + 2
end

p MyModule.my_variable
```

Comment: I did not recommend to mutate a class variable, that's breaking the encapsulation rules. Also not following the Open/Close Principle from SOLID

Comment: @julian This creates a class instance variable (since Modules are classes), right? Not sure how this breaks encapsulation...

Comment: Metaprogramming is an antipattern, that brakes the encapsulation principle.