# Difference Between @ and @@ instance

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-variables

I produce an app with ruby, and benefited from ruby tutorials. So, I meet this syntax (`@@vars`), and want to ask it. (I think it's like a pointer in C or two dimensional array)

`@@vars` AND `@vars`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @@variable mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890118/what-does-variable-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@var` is an instance variable, whereas `@@var` is a class variable. See for example:

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/