# What is the difference between @@ and @ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I just started learning Ruby and I have been unable to find a good explanation on what is the difference between @@ and @ in terms of class variables. If anyone can provide a basic intuitive example, that would be really great. Also are they interchangeable?

Comment: [This](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) site may be of help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A variable prefixed with `@@` is a class variable and one prefixed with `@` is an instance variable.  A great description can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890199/1181886

Comment: Thank you, that linked answer was really helpful!

Answer (score 12):

@ before a variable name : instance variable (one per instance)

@@ before a variable name : static variable (one per class)