# What is the difference between @@ and @ and when should I use one rather than another?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between a variable that has `@@` symbols and that has only one `@` symbol?

For example, if I declare a variable `name` in a class, what's the difference between `@@name`, and `@name`?

I'd appreciate any answer that points me to the right direction or doc :)

Comment: Not sure to which point [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098000/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-ruby) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890118/what-does-variable-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: Your question could be, "What is the difference between `@@` and `@` and when should I use one rather than another?". See [this doc](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/) for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is an instance variable. It is a variable attached to a particular object. These are how you store data on an object.

```
class Thing
  # These two methods are basically what `attr_accessor :stuff` does.
  def stuff=(value)
    @stuff = value
  end

  def stuff
    @stuff
  end
end

f1 = Foo.new
f1.stuff = 42  # f1's @stuff is set to 42

f2 = Foo.new
f2.stuff = 23  # f2's @stuff is set to 23

p f1.stuff  # 42
p f2.stuff  # 23
```

`@@` is a class variable. They are to be avoided because of a quirk: they're shared with all subclasses.

```
class Vehicle
  @@type = 'vehicle'

  def self.type
    @@type
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  # This is the same @@type as in Vehicle
  @@type = 'car'
end

class Plane < Vehicle
  # This is the same @@type as in Vehicle
  @@type = 'plane'
end

p Vehicle.type # plane
p Car.type  # plane
p Plane.type  # plane
```

Instead, use "class instance variables". Everything in Ruby is an object including classes. They are instances of [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html). `class Vehicle ... end` is syntax sugar for `Vehicle = Class.new do ... end`. And like any object, they can have instance variables.

```
# Same as `class Vehicle` just to demonstrate.
Vehicle = Class.new do
  # This is an instance variable on the Vehicle Class object.
  # Not Vehicle.new, but just Vehicle.
  @type = 'vehicle'
  
  def self.type
    @type
  end
end

# class Plane < Vehicle
Plane = Class.new(Vehicle) do
  # This is an instance variable on the Plane Class object.
  @type = 'plane'
end

# And the sugary way.
class Car < Vehicle
  # This is an instance variable on the Car Class object.
  @type = 'car'
end

p Vehicle.type # vehicle
p Car.type  # car
p Plane.type # plane
```

See [Class Instance Variables in Ruby](https://maximomussini.com/posts/ruby-class-variables/) and [The Official Ruby FAQ](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/) for more.