# What is the purpose of prefixing a variable inside a function with the @ symbol?

Tags: ruby

I understand that instance variables inside classes can be denoted by prefixing the variable name with the @ symbol.  There are a few practical applications of this in classes [What does @@variable mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890118/what-does-variable-mean-in-ruby)

What is a practical application of doing this inside a function?

```
def foo
    one = 1
    @two = 2
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an *instance variable*. It's value persists on an instance.

```
class Foo
  def set_baz
    @baz = 1
  end

  def get_baz
    @baz
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.get_baz #=> nil
foo.set_baz
foo.get_baz #=> 1


foo2 = Foo.new
foo.get_baz #=> nil
```

As you can see we can set `@baz` from within any method and it's updated on the instance, where we can fetch it later.

---

The `@` prefix sets and gets instance variable on `self`, whatever `self` is. Say I boot up `irb`, now `self` is an object context created to run code in.  As you create your own classes with your own code, the value of `self` (aka, the context) will change in various methods throughout your app.

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > @foo = 123
 => 123 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > self.instance_variable_get :@foo
 => 123 
2.0.0-p0 :003 > self
 => main
2.0.0-p0 :004 > self.class
 => Object
```

But really, I wouldn't set instance variables unless you are in a class.  You'll just confused yourself and there isn't really a good reason to do it.

I'd say, as a rule of thumb, if you don't know exactly what `self` *is* at a line of code, you shouldn't be setting instance variables on it at all.

Comment: Yes - but what does this mean in a regular function, not a method of a class?

Comment: It's an instance variable on whatever `self` currently is.  Which is likely the global singleton instance of `Kernel` (I think...)  Everything is an instance of something in ruby, and you are doing class based programming wether you realize it or not.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "regular function" in Ruby.  *Everything* is a method on some object somewhere.  As a practical matter, though, if you just use the default object, then anything stored in an `@` variable persists between invocations, and is also visible to other functions called from the same context.  Variables without the `@` go away when the function returns.

Comment: @user784637 See my edit, which explains how instance variables behave without any explicit classes.

Comment: Spelling cop here, *wether* != *whether*, look up [wether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wether) and you'll see why you probably want to use *whether you realize it or not* in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that you might be confusing `@` with `@@`.  The former is tied to a specific instance of a class; the latter is shared by all objects of the class.  To expand on Alex's answer:

```
class Foo
  def set_baz(n)
    @baz = n
  end

  def set_zoo(n)
    @@zoo = n
  end

  def get_baz
    @baz
  end

  def get_zoo
    @@zoo
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Foo.new

foo.set_baz(1) 
foo.get_baz   # 1

bar.set_baz(2)
bar.get_baz   # 2

foo.get_baz   # still 1

foo.set_zoo(3) 
foo.get_zoo   # 3

bar.set_zoo(4) 
bar.get_zoo   # 4

foo.get_zoo   # also 4
```

Comment: A class variable outside of your own class would likely be _way_ more confusing to get your head around than an instance variable. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> What is a practical application of doing this inside a <s>function</s> method?

```
class Dog
  def foo
    one = 1
    @two = 2
  end

  def bar
    puts @two
    puts one
  end

end

d = Dog.new
d.foo
d.bar

--output:--
2

1.rb:9:in `bar': undefined local variable or method `one' for #<Dog:0x00000101086810 @two=2> (NameError)
    from 1.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Local variables, the ones without an @ in front of them, are destroyed when a method finishes executing.

> Yes - but what does this mean in a regular function, not a method of a class?

Instance variables, the ones with a single @ in front of them, attach themselves to whatever object is self at the time they are created:

```
def do_stuff
  puts self   #=>main
  @val = 10
end

do_stuff   

puts self  #=>main
```

That output is a little unusual because self is equal to an object called `main` both inside the def and outside the def.   Usually a def will change self--but a def doesn't change self when the def is at the the top level.

Okay, so if @val attached to an object called main, and self=main, lets print out @val:

```
def do_stuff
  puts self   #=>main
  @val = 10
end

do_stuff 

puts self.val  #`<main>': undefined method `val' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Ahh, yes.  All instance variables are private by default, so let's write some accessors in main's class:

```
def do_stuff
  puts self   #=>main
  @val = 10
end

do_stuff

puts self.class   #=>Object

class Object
  attr_reader :val
end

puts self.val   #=>10
```

Next, a def attaches to whatever the *current class* is when the def is created.  The current class is either equal to self, or if self isn't a class, then the current class is self's class.  In the example above, when do_stuff was created self=main:

```
puts self    #main

def do_stuff
  puts self
  @val = 10
end
```

Because self is not a class, the current class is self's class, which we can see is Object:

```
puts self.class   #Object
```

So do_stuff attaches itself to the Object class, which means it becomes an instance method of the Object class. And for extra points--it actually becomes a private instance method:

```
puts Object.private_methods.grep(/^do/)   #=>do_stuff
```

defs inside classes also attach themselves to to the current class:

```
class Dog
  puts self   #=>Dog

  def bark
    puts "Woof"
  end
end
```

...but unlike at the toplevel, the defs become public instance methods of the class.